# Cannot change sender address using smtp_header_checks

Tags: postfix

Have postfix 2.10. Nondefault options in main.cf:

```
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
relayhost = smtp.company.org
```

/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks :

```
/from:.*/i REPLACE From: somebody@yahoo.co.uk
```

However, tcpdump shows that the following line sent to the relay:

```
MAIL FROM:<root@myserver.localdomain>
```

I'm sending it with local sendmail

Comment: Check this http://serverfault.com/questions/724576/fully-altering-recipient-on-postfix/724890#724890

Comment: @ETL I'm sending with local sendmail; updated the question

Comment: The address in `MAIL FROM` is envelope address, the address in `From:` header is header address. Which one did you want to rewrite?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750194/why-does-email-need-an-envelope-and-what-does-the-envelope-mean

Answer (score 1):

I like generic maps for this task, but besides that you can't send from yahoo this way.

```
postconf -e smtp_generic_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/generic
echo 'root icantsendfrom@yahoo.co.uk' >> /etc/postfix/generic
postmap /etc/postfix/generic
service postfix restart
```

to send from yahoo.

```
postconf -e relayhost=smtp.yahoo.co.uk:465 
echo 'smtp.yahoo.co.uk username:password' >>/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd 
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

if postfix is installed, you are using it even if you run the sendmail command one one or the other can be installed, postfix will install a sendmail wrapper.